# What version of Scala does Hortonwork HDP 2.1 support?

Tags: scala, hadoop, mapreduce, cascading, scalding

I'm building Scalding job using Scala 2.10.4. Its successfully creating the job. But when I run the job in my Hortonworks it throwing the following exception.

[image]

According to some answers, this issue happens due to the conflicting scala version.

Can you please explain me this problem? I searched for a scala version in my Hortonworks I can't find it. Am I doing anything wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stacktrace at the bottom is showing that your job throws in `HadoopUtils.getRootQueue` where you try to execute `.get` on an `Option` instance, that happens to be a `None`. So I don't think this is a version problem, rather you should either use `.getOrElse` or pattern match on the option, and handle the `None` case appropriately.

Also, you can write a Scalding unit test to catch these errors early before you submit the job to the cluster.